# how to solve syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) (0)

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

```
<tbody> 
@if(count($articles) > 0)
 @foreach(@articles->all() as $article)

<tr class="table-active">
  <th ></th>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
      <a herf="{{ url('')}}" ><button class="label label-primary">Read |</button></a>
      <a herf="{{ url('')}}" ><button class="label label-success"> Update |</button></a>
      <a herf="{{ url('')}}" ><button class="label label-danger">Delete |</button></a>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Contoller:

```
class CreatesController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        $articles =Article::all();
        return view('home',['article'=>$articles]);
    }
}
```

Getting the following error.

```
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelcrud\resources\views\home.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 @foreach(@articles->all() as $article)
```

with

```
 @foreach($articles as $article)
```

Answer (score 1):

Return to the view using the following syntax

`return view('home', compact('articles'));`

and use the following for `foreach`

`@foreach ( $articles as $article )
  //your code here
 @endforeach`